# Tag Java source code from Mantis issue

Tags: netbeans, tags, mantis

I used Netbeans 8.0.2 with Mantis 1.2.19 and I would like to like my source code with the Mantis issue repository.

Let's take a example: when a new issue occurs, I would like to tag my sources code though comments line to indicate where the modification has been done, like this:

```
/*
* bug:0000045: Problem of array etc...
*/
```

Somebody knows if it's possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach svn/git changesets to a Mantis issue by using the Source-Integration plugin available at https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/source-integration

Answer (score 0):

I used Netbeans, Mantis and SVN for many month but my answer is already opened. I think it's not possible to use by this way.

I need to use SVN/Git repository to track changes and use compare to see the differences between version 1.0 and 2.0.

In fact the Netbeans plug-in can be a good solution to see versionning.

Thanks for your answer libregeek!